# Previously developed SharePoint 2013 template workflows are not opening in SharePoint designer 2013 in SPOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I had created list workflows with **SharePoint 2013 templates** almost 2 years before from today in client's SharePoint Online tenant using SharePoint designer.

Recently, when I have tried to edit this workflow using SharePoint 2013 designer, it gives below errors:

- For the first time, when you try to click on workflow it shows:

  > server side activities have been updated you need to restart
  >   sharepoint designer
- After traversing back to workflows folder, and click on workflow it shows:

  > windows workflow foundation part of .net framework 3.0 must be installed to 
  >   use this feature
- Then it shows error:

  > SharePoint Designer cannot display the item.
  >   [image]

I am using SharePoint designer 2013 with 64 bit.
I already have **installed/updated** designer with below installations:

- SP Designer SP1
- spd2013-kb2863836-fullfile-x64-glb.exe
- spd2013-kb3114337-fullfile-x64-glb.exe
- spd2013-kb3114721-fullfile-x64-glb.exe

Also tried solutions provided in below URLs, but none of them work:

- [Problem when opening SharePoint Online workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214488/problem-when-opening-sharepoint-online-workflows-in-sharepoint-designer-2013)
- [error: server side activities have been updated you need to restart sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218892/error-server-side-activities-have-been-updated-you-need-to-restart-sharepoint-d)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ca5f8465-2bbd-4d20-8dc7-0b4bf02e3c7a/not-able-to-open-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-in-sharepoint-designer-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Strangely, when I tried to create a new workflow on same list, it works properly but for older workflows, it's not working.

I have checked same in development and production sites and in both sites, we are getting this issue. Even I have tried SharePoint designers on different machines but the error is same.

Please let me know if there is any solution to resolve this.

**Note:** *I am very much aware with the policy of duplicating the questions in the forum, but the answers posted in forum were not worked for me that's why I have posted this new question. So please take a note before marking this question as duplicate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I was clearing cache by removing files/folders from the paths suggested in many of the answers, I was not able to open workflow in designer. Even I have tried to remove cache using PowerShell but no luck.

Then I got one l[ink](https://ehikioya.com/clear-sharepoint-designer-cache/), and I followed the steps to **disable SharePoint designer cache** completely and it works for me.

Here are the steps I followed so far:

- Open SharePoint designer, Navigate to the “File” menu.
- Then go to Options >> General >> Application Options.
- On the "General" tab, under the "General" heading, deselect "Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions"

  - In my case, I have also deselect "Preload site data during the site open process"

  [image]
- restart the designer.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online, there is the Workflow auto cleanup timer job, it will delete tasks and instances in the workflow instance table for workflows that were marked completed more than n days in the past.

The n is specified in the workflow association.

So, the previous workflow cannot be opened in SharePoint designer.

More reference:

[Default timer jobs in SharePoint 2013. It also can work for sharepoint online.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2013)