# SharePoint designer 2013 couldn't show up my existing workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I just have a new laptop machine and tried to install SharePoint designer 2013. When i open the site using designer, it opens , but blank workflow. I taught , the cache clear issue and i cleared it. Still, doesn't show up existing workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [other post here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214488/problem-when-opening-sharepoint-online-workflows-in-sharepoint-designer-2013?rq=1), they suggest installed Service Pack 1 to clear the issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1

Answer (score 1):

Did you, by chance, try to open it using the Visio Designer? **(DO NOT DO THIS FOR COMPLEX WORKFLOWS)** I have done this for a complex workflow and it broke the Text-Based Designer. I'd also look to reinstall SharePoint Designer, as reinstalling fixed this for me.